# PowerShell Comparing Date issue

Tags: powershell

I created a small scrip that have do to a couple of thinks.

- get string from description field from user in specific container
- take part of this string (substring method) that holds date information
- convert this string to date format
- compare this formated string with a current date - 30 days and do sth

The problem is that comparing is not working correctly. I tried do recognise date that is older than 30 days and do something but i see that comparison not always work. sometimes it does not recognize that date is less then - 30 days from current day
Script below

```
$DateMaxTime = (Get-date).AddDays(-30)
$DateFormatMaxTime = Get-Date $DateMaxTime  -Format dd/MM/yyyy
$getData = get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * -SearchBase "OU=Disabled,OU=Control,OU=x,OU=x,DC=x,DC=x,DC=x" `
|where {$_.Description -like "LEFT*"} |select name,samaccountname,description


Foreach ($Data IN $getData){
$DataPart = $null
$DataPart=$Data.description
$DatePart= $DataPart.substring(5,10)
$FinalDate = [datetime]::ParseExact($DatePart,'dd/MM/yyyy',$null) 
$FinalDateFormat = Get-Date $FinalDate -Format dd/MM/yyyy

If ($FinalDateFormat -lt $DateFormatMaxTime  ){ Write-Host "$($Data.samaccountname), $($Data.description) moved to deleteMe" }
else{ Write-Host "$($Data.samaccountname), $($Data.description) still in disabled" }

}
```

Below output shows me the wrong results (as example i did it for one user - >

[image]

Based on this logic the value $FinalDateFormat that hold date -> 31-12-2018 is less then value $DateFormatMaxTime  that hold this date -> 25-06-2019 but it still applies else statement ...

I am not sure why, i did something wrong with date conversion ?

Comment: I would compare the datetime versions of the dates rather than the string versions.

Comment: meaning? this was converted to date format

Comment: `If ($FinalDate -lt $DateMaxTime)`.  `get-date -format` makes them strings.

Comment: now it behaves properly but why ...?

Comment: `$finaldate.gettype()` and `$datemaxtime.gettype()`  They are [datetime] not [string] like the other two.

Comment: i see .... thanks for explanation, i did not know that - format.date converts date to strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put the comments as the answer:

I would compare the datetime versions of the dates rather than the string versions.

```
If ($FinalDate -lt $DateMaxTime)
```

Running

```
get-date -format
```

makes them strings.

```
$finaldate.gettype(); $datemaxtime.gettype()
```

shows the types.  They are [datetime], not [string] like the other two.

Comment: Although this answer hits the nail on the head in terms of the issue (string conversion by way of `Get-Date -Format`) - [some additional background can be found in this related answer as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60096851/15243610)