# Powershell - compare date with CSV date

Tags: powershell, datetime, datetime-format

I am trying to compare a date entered with a date from a CSV and display a message if the date entered is before the date in the CSV.

Am having difficulty, unsure if I need to convert the date in the CSV from string for it to be compared correctly.

Have got this far with the code:

```
$CSV=Import-Csv C:\Users\person\Desktop\date.csv 
$InputDate = Get-Date -Format "MM/dd/yyyy" (Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the date')
$CreatedDate = Get-Date -Format "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm" $CSV.updated

if($InputDate -gt $CreatedDate) {
  write-host "Input Newer"
}
else {
  write-host "Input Older"
}
```

The comparison doesn't seem to work correctly.

CSV formatted as below (contains a single row, so `$CSV.updated` can be assumed to contain a *single* date string):

```
updated
11/07/2016 16:14
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse the date in string to datetime type to do the date comparisons.

```bsh
$CSV = Import-Csv C:\Users\person\Desktop\date.csv 
$InputDate = [datetime]::Parse( $(Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the date (MM/dd/yyyy)') )
$CreatedDate = [datetime]::Parse( $CSV.updated )
if($InputDate -gt $CreatedDate)
{write-host "Input Newer"}
else
{write-host "Input Older"}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Kiran Patnayakuni's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60094223/45375) provides an effective solution; let me make it clearer what the problem was:

- **You seemingly expected `-Format "MM/dd/yyyy"` to specify an *input parsing* format; in fact, it formats the *output*, which then becomes a `[string]`**.

  - For meaningful date comparison you need a `[datetime]` instance, however.
- Your arguments to the (implied) `-Date` parameter (`(Read-Host ...)`, `$csv.updated`) were *implicitly* parsed, based on the standard formats recognized by the *current culture* ([`System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)).

Therefore:

- If your arguments are already properly recognized by the *implicit* parsing (as your acceptance of Kiran's answer suggests), the solution is to simply *remove the `-Format` arguments* from your code:

  ```
    # Parse each input string implicitly, based on the current culture,
    # and output a [datetime] instance, which will compare as expected
    # with `-gt`
    $InputDate = Get-Date (Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the date')
    $CreatedDate = Get-Date $CSV.updated
  ```
- If, by contrast, you do need to parse by the `"MM/dd/yyyy"` format string explicitly in order for your arguments to be recognized, call .NET method `[datetime]::ParseExact(<string>, <format>[, <culture>])` ([`System.DateTime.ParseExact`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime.ParseExact)); e.g.:

  ```
    # Note: The input string must match the format *exactly*
    $InputDate = [datetime]::ParseExact(
      (Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the date'), # input string
      "MM/dd/yyyy", # format string
      $null  # default to the current culture's rules
    )
  ```

Read on for background information.

---

#### [`Get-Date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date) input and output formats an data types:

**`-Format "MM/dd/yyyy"` doesn't specify an *input* parsing format, it specifies the *output* string-formatting format**, which has two implications:

- ***String* input passed to input parameter `-Date` (which the first *positional* argument is bound to) is *implicitly* parsed** as `[datetime]`, based on the ***standard* string formats recognized by the *current culture***<sup>[1]</sup>; in effect, the following is called behind the scenes:

  ```
    [datetime]::Parse((Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the date'), [cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture)
  ```

  - (Omitting `[cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture` in the call above has the same effect.)
  - **Caveat**: **When you *cast* a string to `[datetime]`**, it is the ***invariant* culture (`[cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture`, based on US-English) that is applied**, which PowerShell often does for stability of code across cultures; that a cmdlet such as `Get-Date` is *not* culture-invariant is a historical accident that won't be corrected for fear of breaking old code; see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6989) for background. For instance, with culture `fr-FR` (French) in effect, `[datetime] '12/1]` yields *December 1st* (month first), whereas `Get-Date -Date '12/1'` yields *January 12* (day first).
- The `Get-Date` command **will return a (formatted) *string* rather than a `[datetime]` instance**; that is, the `[datetime]` instance implicitly parsed on input is formatted based on the format string passed to `-Format`, based on the rules of the *current* culture; if `$dt` contains a `[datetime]` instance, **`-Format "MM/dd/yyyy"` is the equivalent of** (note how a direct call to [`System.DateTime.ToString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime.ToString) gives you the option to specify a *different* culture, which `-Format` doesn't):

  ```
    $dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", [cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture)
  ```

**(As of PowerShell v7.0), the [`Get-Date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date) cmdlet has *no* support for specifying a format string for *input* parsing.**

- As stated, passing a string to `-Date` causes it to be *implicitly* parsed, based on the *standard date/time formats* recognized by the *current culture*.
- You'll have to **call .NET method `[datetime]::ParseExact(<string>, <format>[, <culture>])` ([`System.DateTime.ParseExact`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime.ParseExact))** directly, as demonstrated in the top section.
- Once you have a `[datetime]` instance, you may pass it (via `-Date`) to `Get-Date -Format` to get a formatted string representation for the *current culture*; alternatively, you can call `.ToString(<format>[, <culture>])` ([`System.DateTime.ToString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime.ToString)) directly on the instance, which also gives you the option to format for a *different culture*.

**As for `Get-Date` input and output *data types***:

**Fundamentally, how the *input* is passed (specific arguments) determines the how the resulting `[datetime]` instance is interpreted, based on how the cmdlet chooses the instance's
[`.Kind`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime.Kind) property value (`Utc`, `Local`, or `Unspecified`).**

The `.Kind` property value determines what specific global point in time, if any, a `[datetime]` instance represents. The `.Kind` value can also affect an instance's string representation, depending on what specific formatting is applied (notably, inclusion of time-zone information).

The resulting `[datetime]` instance is:

- either: output *directly* (by default)
- or: if a `-Format` argument was passed, is the basis for deriving the requested *string representation* (`[string]`).

`Get-Date` determines the `.Kind` property value as follows:

- With *no* `-Date` argument, you get a `Local` instance (representing the current point in time)

  - (Unless a string is *also* passed to `-Date`), using the various offset parameters, such as `-Year` and `-Day`, produces a `Local` instance as well.
- With a `-Date` argument that already *is* of type `[datetime]`, that instance is used as-is, which means the existing `.Kind` property value is retained.
- With a *string* `-Date` argument (which gets implicitly parsed), the `.Kind` value will be `Unspecified` (representing an *abstract* point in time, without reference to a specific time zone), including if combined with parameters such as `-Year`.
- A *numeric* `-Date` argument (e.g, `637165787436900010`) is interpreted as a [`System.DateTime.Ticks`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime.Ticks) value, which also produces an `Unspecified` instance.

Note: PowerShell [Core] 7.1 will introduce an `-AsUTC` switch that makes the output / to-be-string-formatted instance be of kind `Utc`; `-AsLocal` and `-AsUnspecified` switches (and/or an `-AsKind <kind>` parameter) are also being discussed - see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11731).

---

<sup>[1] If the input already is a `[datetime]` instance, it is used as-is.</sup>